# Correctly clean filter in draining pipe

Tags: plumbing

[image]

It looks like the washing machine draining pipe is clogged.
The pipe contains a component which I never saw before (see picture). Is it some kind of filter? If so, does it have a technical name and what is the correct procedure to clean it?

Answer (score 1):

> **The pipe contains a component which I never saw before**

Me too

> **Is it some kind of filter?**

It might be a filter, it might be some kind of device that lets water out but keeps smells in. Though there should be a normal U,S or P trap for that purpose. It could be a type of bottle trap known as an inline trap. It has some similarities to a [straight-through pedestal basin trap](https://goo.gl/images/LkNjUm)

> **what is the correct procedure to clean it?**

No idea but it does look like there are parts which can be unscrewed.

[image: waste-pipe assembly]

Those collars have ribs which makes them look like they were designed to be rotated by hand. I would start by undoing the metal screw at the very top that holds the funnel to the wall.